# Can I create custom keyboard dictionaries on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, keyboard

I am trying to create a keyboard dictionary loaded with specific terms for my co-workers. Ideally, those terms would be separated from the user's actual personal dictionary and could be enabled / disabled on request.

Is writing such an app possible? And if not, can I have an iPhone app install the terms in the user dictionary?

Thanks for any hints and best regards

Pascal

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it would need to be done manually per device: [how-to on lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5822520/how-to-add-new-custom-words-to-your-iphones-autocomplete-dictionary).

Comment: Thanks for the Input. I presume there is no automated way in the Cocoa framework to achieve this then?